# Dealing with a curriculum database

Tags: mysql

Okay, I have 3 tables:

1. Students
2. Offered_subjects
3. Enrollees_list

Students will contain all the information of the students of the school
Offered_subjects will contain all the subjects offered by the school
Enrollees_list will contain all information about what subject a students is enrolled in and will also contain remarks for that subject (pass or fail).

Now, the subjects in offered_subjects contain courses that have prerequisites (ie. before qualifying for MySQL101, the student mas have a passing remark in DBMS101)

The categories of prerequisites are:

1. Academic Year
2. Semester
3. Subject

Note that not all the subjects listed in offered_subjects have all the categories for its prerequisite. Some require to finish a certain subject, some require that the student must be in a certain academic year (ie, 3rd year), and some have all three.

What's required for the program is to display all the students that are qualified for a selected subject.

Let's say: MySQL101 has prerequisite of 2nd year, 2nd sem, DBMS101

I need to list all the students that are on their 2nd year, 2nd sem, and have a passing remark in DBMS101.

This would be easy if all the subjects have same categories for its prerequisites where I can put the same queries in the `where` clause, but my problem is that, again, not all the subjects listed in offered_subjects have all the categories for its prerequisite.

I'm new to MySQL and it's kind of confusing to me at the moment.

How do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you have the following columns on the Offered_subjects table:

- Req_year
- Req_semester
- Req_subject

If one of your subjects don't have values on this column, you can ignore this check for this column. Something like:

```
Select ... where (Subject.req_year is null OR Student.year >= Subject.req_year) ...
```

This way, required year will not be taken into account if it's null.

(note: I'm not completely sure of syntax right now, but that's the idea).

Comment: Yes, I do have those 3 on that table. I will try your suggestion and see if it works. Thank you.

Comment: You should use `IS NULL`, not `= NULL`, it won't work correctly otherwise.

Comment: Yes, I figured that out. Unfortunately, I'm still having problems when the subject has all the prerequisite categories.